# Windows Phone 7 - How to Play an MPEG Video?

Tags: windows-phone-7, playback, mediaelement, mpeg

Is there a way to play or convert .mpg videos in Windows Phone 7? It does not work in a MediaElement. I want to show this video:
http://sohowww.nascom.nasa.gov/data/LATEST/current_eit_171.mpg. If not, can you recommend any ways to do this server side on an IIS server?

Comment: Does converting the video to some other format beforehand a solution for you?